# Simple Question about Proof By Contradiction and Induction

Tags: real-analysis, logic, solution-verification, soft-question

I encountered a situation in which I believe that I was missing something on understanding the proof by contradiction.

Consider the following simple statement.

> If $k\geq 1$, then $3^k > 2^k$.

Usually, one can prove this by induction. However, I was wondering what if I pursue a proof by contradiction. That is, assume $k\geq 1$ but $3^k \leq 2^k$. Then, if $k=1$, we see that $3\leq 2$, which is a contradiction. Hence, we must have $3^k > 2^k$. Is my logic correct here? I was bothered about my thinking above because it seems to only take one instance $k=1$ to make the contradiction without checking other $k=2,3,4,...$ Any comment is appreciated.

Comment: Induction is do-able, except that $k \in \Bbb{R_{\geq 1}}$, rather than $\Bbb{Z_{\geq 1}}$.  So induction won't work re Real values of $k$.

Comment: The original statement says $3^k>2^k$ for *all* $k\ge1$. For a contradiction you want to assume this is not true. So you assume there exists *some* value of $k\ge1$ for which $3^k\le2^k$. Just showing that this value is not $k=1$ does not establish a contradiction because there are infinitely many other values that $k$ could be. Remember that the negation of a "for all" statement is a "there exists" statement, not another for-all statement.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Ah..I see. "there is" a $k\geq 1$ such that $3^k \leq 2^k.$ So by checking one $k$ failure does not preclude the existence of the "true $k$"...Thanks a lot !

Comment: @Fianra Exactly.

Comment: You logic only proofs that $3^1 > 2^1$ and not that that $3^k > 2^k$ for *all* $k$.   The statement "not all dogs are friendly" is not the same statement as "all dogs are not friendly".

Comment: Or consider this.....  Prove $3^k - 25 < 2^k$.  Let's do a prove by contradiction.  Assume $3^k -25 \ge 2^k$.  Then $3^1 - 25 \ge 2^1$ so $3 -25 \ge 2$ so $3 \ge 27$ which is a contradiction.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trouble is the negation of "For all $k \ge 1$, $3^k >2^k$" is *not*  "For all $k \ge 1$, $3^k \le 2^k$".  It is "For at least one $k \ge 1$, $3^k \le 2^k$".

For any statement $P(n)$ there are three options:

1. It is always true
2. It is sometimes true and sometimes false
3. It is never true.

So the negation of 1) is not 3).  The negation of 1) is either 2) or 3).  Or in other words.  "It is false at least once".